# How can I apply an Arrayformula for multiple cells on Google Sheets which includes fixed and variable cells?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to apply an arrayformula to my worksheet on Google Sheets, which works good when I drop-down the formula to the cells below. But because I have quite much data, I need to use the arrayformula for this formula and I can't find a solution how to apply the variable cell (in this example B11 and C11) to all cells below it.

The screenshot should explain my problem very well.

[image: 0]

```
=COUNTIF((ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B11>$B$4:$B$7,IF(C11>$C$4:$C$7,1,0),0)))=1,IF((ARRAYFORMULA(IF($K$4:$K$7>$J$4:$J$7,1,0)))=1,1,0),0))),"1")
```

Here a link to my file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c17IQCujy3cQwDOcbJUpm3iCgJHCbD8QRbK0aQfVtQA/edit?usp=sharing

The output is in the green field

Comment: share a copy of  your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
 IF(IF(INDIRECT("B11:B"&COUNTA(B11:B)+10)>TRANSPOSE(B4:B7),
    IF(INDIRECT("C11:C"&COUNTA(C11:C)+10)>TRANSPOSE(C4:C7), 1, 0), 0)=1,
 IF(IF(TRANSPOSE(K4:K7)>TRANSPOSE(J4:J7), 1, 0)=1, 1, 0), 0), {1; 1; 1; 1}))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image]

Comment: If I extend the range (in the example it would be B4:B7 and C4:C7) to lets say B4:B1000 and C4:C1000, i get the error "The resulting array was too large." I also added enough "1;" at the end. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: can you share your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c17IQCujy3cQwDOcbJUpm3iCgJHCbD8QRbK0aQfVtQA/edit?usp=sharing

check Combination!O3 please

Comment: yeah, I see the issue now. your array is ENORMOUS (16000+ rows) and MMULT cant handle it all in one go, therefore you need to divide your formula into smaller chunks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhVeV.png

Comment: wow great you made it work! thank you so much. If you now tell me where I have to add 0 and 1, when I want to add the IF-statements for all 5 columns in "Data", you are my hero.

Comment: Also, why is the result over 100k if there are only 1000 rows in "data"?

Comment: 1000 rows on Data sheet serve only as a comparison against to your true dataset which is in C and D columns. there you have more than 16k rows

Comment: No cell Combination!O3 would be read: How many times were the cells Data!C4:C998 smaller than Combination!C3 AND Data!C4:998 greater than Combination!D3 AND Data!J4:J998 greater than Data!K4:K998. Maximum would be if all 1000 rows would fit into that criteria, not more

Comment: @Anon11011 indeed. fixed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4yq.png